# Fast_SleepSort, divide sleep time by a constant - improvement has some problems

Tags: bash

Feeling incredibly pleased with myself, I rewrote the bash sleep sort to sleep not a second, but less than second.

```
#!/bin/bash
function f() {
#sleep miliseconds!
sleepytime=$(echo "scale=6;$1/1000" | bc)
sleep $sleepytime
echo "$1"
}
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    f "$1" &
    shift
done
wait
```

Now, this works quite well.

```
$time ./fast_sleepsort.sh 10 20 5 4
4
5
10
20

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.018s
sys 0m0.035s
```

But all is not well.

```
$ ./fast_sleepsort.sh 10 20 5 4 4 3 3 3
5
4
4
3
3
3
10
20
```

Which is clearly not sorted.

What is giving this modified version of SleepSort problems, and does it give us insight into SleepSort's hardware dependence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a process in the background takes some time. 3ms are too short, starting the process and shifting (and whatever else happens at your machine at the same time) takes more than that. Try using `$1/100` instead.

Comment: `SLEEP_FACTOR=100
sleepytime=$(echo "scale=6;$1/$SLEEP_FACTOR" | bc)
sleep $sleepytime` - this does work. So it's the time taken to start the process in the background that's making different sleeps bump over each other?

Comment: I guess what the sort actually sorts by is wall time, so any fudge you have around that can change the sorting order if it's in the same order of magnitude as your values - and it looks like milliseconds are short enough to qualify.